# Standard List Controller extension not working

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I am preparing for the PD1 exam and I was practicing an example on the standard list controllers using extension. The extension class limits the opportunity to show only 2 records but it is showing more than 2 records. Can someone help me to understand where I am going wrong and how the setController.setSelected method works?

**Extension Class**

```
public  class accExtension {
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setController;
 
public accExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController setController) {
    this.setController = setController;
    
    Opportunity [] records = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity LIMIT 2];
    setController.setSelected(records);
}
}
```

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opps" extensions="accExtension">
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opps}" var="acc">
        <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!acc.StageName}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>    
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your answer will come from [Chapter 4 of VF in Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) - in particular, the section entitled `Advanced Filtering—Using Standard Set Controllers Inside Custom Controllers`.

Comment: Thanks @cropredy Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Documentation for setSelected --> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_access_data.htm